# How to prevent logging out / losing screen after closing RDP

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2019

I have an application that performs click on screen that's running on Windows 2019 Server instance

but the thing is that when I close RDP, then application stops working (clicking)

I suspect that this is caused by User logging out when I close RDP (using "X" button).

Is there any way to "don't lose screen" when I close RDP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

by using the "X" button on your RDP session you do not get logged off. You will be disconnected and your user session is still there. Anyway there is a Windows-GPO that can be used to set a time limit on disconnected sessions.

`Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Session Time Limits`

There should be a setting `Set time limit for disconnected sessions`. Check if it is `Not Configured` or `Enabled` with `Never`.

If this does not solve your Problem it is probably a problem with the application that needs a connected User Session.

Greetings.

Comment: How do you set that in your PowerShell profile, I wonder...
Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Session Time Limits/Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions/enabled

Answer (score 0):

To set the "Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions" using PowerShell, follow these steps:
Open PowerShell with administrator privileges.
Type the following command and press Enter:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxIdleTime" -Value

Replace  with the number of minutes you want to set as the idle time limit. For example, if you want to set the limit to 30 minutes, type:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxIdleTime" -Value 30
Type the following command and press Enter:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxDisconnectedTime" -Value

Replace  with the number of minutes you want to set as the disconnected time limit. For example, if you want to set the limit to 60 minutes, type:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "MaxDisconnectedTime" -Value 60
Type the following command and press Enter:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "fResetBroken" -Value 1
Finally, type the following command and press Enter:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name "fPolicyUnclear" -Value 1

This enables the policy and applies the changes.
Close PowerShell.

These commands will set the idle and disconnected time limits for Remote Desktop Services sessions.